# examples of infinitely differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

What types of infinitely differentibale functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ have the following property?

$$\lbrace x : |f(x)| = 1 \rbrace \nsubseteq cl \lbrace x : |f(x)| > 1 \rbrace$$

where $cl$ denotes closure of a set.

Comment: Why does the title mention infinitely differentiable functions?  This seems to be unrelated to your question.

Comment: I forgot to put it in the description, I'm interested in infinitely differentiable functions having the said property.

Comment: Every infinitely differentiable function such that $|f(x)|=1$ at least once and $|f(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x$ is an example (this condition is sufficient but not necessary).  $f(x)\equiv 1$ is the simplest.  What do you mean by "what types"?  Do you just want some examples?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: I have some examples at hand, but am interested if there are some pathological examples

Comment: What are your examples, and what do you mean by pathological?

Comment: @user58191 yes. Take any infinitely differentiable function with a local maximim $f(x_0)>0$ at $x_0$. Then $\frac{1}{f(x_0)}f(x)$ has this property.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: My examples were all of the type in the answer below. By pathological, I meant in the sense that I'm looking for "strange"/"weird" functions with this property. (like in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740/useful-examples-of-pathological-functions).

Comment: @user58191: *Every* example is of the type in the answer below.  Many of the pathologies in the question you link to involve discontinuous or nondifferentiable functions, which wouldn't meet your criteria.  There are infinitely differentiable nonanalytic examples, if that would serve you (e.g., bump functions).

Answer (score 3):

A continuous function has this property if and only if there is a point $x$ for which $|f(x)| = 1$ and $|f(y)| \leq 1$ for all $y$ in a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: In the infinitely differentiable case, necessary conditions for such $x$ include $f'(x)=0$.  If $f(x)=1$, then $f''(x)\leq 0$, and if $f(x)=-1$, then $f''(x)\geq 0$.